# Probability that as many heads came out as tails, with the $12$th toss being the first toss after which the numbers of heads and tails became equal.

Tags: probability

We toss a fair coin $12$ times.

1. Determine the probability that as many heads fall out as tails.
2. Determine the probability that as many heads came out as tails, with the $12$th toss being the first toss after which the numbers of heads and tails became equal.

The first point is easy since we can see that it's Bernoulli process and count the probability of $6$ successes in $12$ trials. That will be:
$$P(X = 6) = {{12}\choose{6}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^6\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^6 = {{12}\choose{6}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{12} = \frac{12!}{(12-6)!} \cdot \frac{1} {2^{12}} = \frac{924}{4096}$$

---

The second part is more tricky and I wanted to ask if I did that one correct.

If we consider $12$ tosses, we know that the results of first one and the last one must be different - only that way we can 'start' with advantage of one side of coin and then reduce it to 0 in the last one. Therefore we can have 2 possibilities at this point:

1. we start with heads and finish with tails,
2. we start with tails and finish with heads.

Now, between first and the last toss there are 10 tosses that can't result in bringing the advantage of side chosen by the first toss to 0. They must however result in bringing the advantage to 1 before the last toss (so that it can be reduced to 0 in the last toss). Therefore I thought that for every result of toss building up the advantage we need another one, opposite result - that way we would "cancel" the advantage build by the former one. Therefore we need to pair up the 10 tosses in such way that the first toss result is the one building the advantage and the second one is the one reducing it. Therefore we need only to choose places for pairs (the order inside every pair is determined by the result of first-last toss that is already chosen):
$${{10}\choose{2}}{{8}\choose{2}}{{6}\choose{2}}{{4}\choose{2}}{{2}\choose{2}}$$

Taking all that together we get:
$$2{{10}\choose{2}}{{8}\choose{2}}{{6}\choose{2}}{{4}\choose{2}}{{2}\choose{2}} = 2 \cdot \frac{10!}{2!(10-2)!} \cdot \frac{8!}{2!(8-2)!} \cdot \frac{6!}{2!(6-2)!} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!(4-2)!} = 2 \cdot \frac{10 \cdot 9}{2} \cdot \frac{8 \cdot 7}{2} \cdot \frac{6 \cdot 5}{2} \cdot \frac{4 \cdot 3}{2} = $$
$$= 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 226800 $$

Could that be correct? The result seems to be a bit off for me (too big).

Comment: is the answer $\frac{84}{2^{12}}$ ?

Comment: It cannot possibly be correct because it's more than $2^{12}$...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel what is more than $2^{12}$

Comment: @zynox $226800$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat each head/tail as a $(1,1)/(1,-1)$ step respectively. Then an admissible sequence for the second problem is a path from $(0,0)$ to $(12,0)$ that never touches the horizon except at its endpoints.

We can trim the first and last steps to get a length-$10$ path that by itself does not cross the horizon in the middle, but may touch it. The number of such paths is twice the fifth Catalan number – twice because the first step may be head or tail – hence $2×42=84$. The probability is therefore $\frac{84}{4096}=\frac{21}{1024}$.

Comment: i feel your solution is correct except the catalan number you should have used is 42 not 14

Comment: @zynox oops, I was thinking in Maple terms for too long...

Comment: That's right. Thank you!